# Execute a task after some delay and stop it if running into an infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to execute a task with an initial delay and be able to stop it if it gets stuck into an infinite loop.

I checked [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), but that will cancel the timerTask after it completes.
I want that running task to be stopped before completion.

Comment: You can cancel the task from some other thread if you wish to. You just have to handle the interruption in the worker.

Comment: How do you detect an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture can help you
But instead use of infinite loop better(if you can) use while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()). That can help you stop your task.

Example:

```
 final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    final ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    schedule.cancel(true);
    System.out.println("Stopped");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: Can't implement this way as it will check for thread interrupt after executing the task, there in the while loop.   But i want to interrupt the thread in the middle of the task if it is Running and not completed.

Comment: Then you can use Thread.stop, but this method not recommended, because in this case application state unpredictable(more details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). I advise solve this problem through interrupt.

Comment: But how can i use Thread.stop as i want to create n number of threads and every thread should be executed after some delay. and i should be able to stop any thread in the middle if task not completed and thread is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a task with the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). You can set 2 parameters, the **delay** before it starts and the **period**, which is basically how often you want to wait between 2 execution of the task.

Note that you can also schedule one shot task with an initial delay.

As for the second part of your question, you can handle the exiting in 2 ways.

1. The task itself should stop if it encountered an unexpected situation.
2. The executor of the task can stop the task. You can achieve this either by using a [timeout mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), or by using a cancel mechanism.

Comment: i want to stop it gracefully so 1st option wont work and 2nd option will also not work as as there may be a case i want to cancel before the timeout. Cancel api will also not work as it will not cancel the running task.

Comment: Having the task to stop itself feels like the most natural option to me. I don’t see why you say it’s not graceful. It’s difficult for another thread to stop your task at the moment you want it unless your task signals it in someway. You can argue that if the task is able to signal that  it needs to be stopped, then it can stop by itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly terminate a running thread from the outside; the task must be programmed in a way that checks whether it was interrupted.

Something like

```
Runnable task = () -> while(!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // do your actual work here
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

then you can meaningfully do

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ScheduledFuture<?> future = scheduler.schedule(task, DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try { 
    // wait for task to finish
    future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} catch (TimeoutException to) {
    // "endless loop" detected
    future.cancel();
} catch (ExecutionException|InterruptedException x) {}
```

As an example in the documentation that it's not really reliable to stop a thread is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)):

> If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted **in an attempt to stop** the task.

but also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) (most relevant I guess)

> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.